# QGraphicsView freeze after scaling

Tags: c++, qt

I am on **Windows** with **Qt 4.7**.

I have a bug in my `qgraphicsview`/`qgraphicsscene` whereby after scaling the view, something is causing a "hang" which appears to be a recursive/infinite loop in the event loop.

I apologize for not having a simple, complete code example; I will describe the symptoms and situation as best I can, and I'm hoping somebody will have an idea or two I can try:

I have subclassed `QGraphicsView`, `QGraphicsScene`, and `QGraphicsItem`. For example, `wheelEvent` in `QGraphicsView` has been subclassed to do the following:

```
scaleView(pow((double)2, -event->delta() / 240.0));
```

where

```
void MyGraphicsView::scaleView(qreal scaleFactor)
{
    qreal factor = transform().scale(scaleFactor, scaleFactor).mapRect(QRectF(0, 0, 1, 1)).width();
    if (factor < 0.07 || factor > 100)
        return;

    scale(scaleFactor, scaleFactor);
}
```

The constructor of my `graphicsview` subclass is as follows:

```
MyGraphicsView(QWidget *parent) :
  QGraphicsView(parent)
 {
  setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);
  setTransformationAnchor(AnchorUnderMouse);
  setCacheMode(QGraphicsView::CacheNone);
  setViewportUpdateMode(QGraphicsView::FullViewportUpdate);
  setDragMode(QGraphicsView::ScrollHandDrag);  
 }
```

My subclass of QGraphicsItem constructor is as follows:

```
MyGraphicsItem(QGraphicsObject *parent) :
 QGraphicsObject(parent), 
  _colour(qrand() % 256, qrand() % 256, qrand() % 256),
  _collapsed(false)
{  
  setFlag(ItemIsMovable);
  setFlag(ItemSendsGeometryChanges);
  setCacheMode(DeviceCoordinateCache);
  setZValue(-1);
  expandedPosition(this->pos());
}
```

I can isolate the problem to a call to the `wheelEvent`, or other event which calls `QGraphicsView::scaleView`.

If there is a `MyGraphicsItem` visible, then trying to paint (or something caused by painting) causes the whole system to hang. I think this is a loop in the event loop, but to get out of it (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>del</kbd> to bring up "Start Task Manager", then <kbd>esc</kbd> to cancel) I lose the loop I was in.

The loop seems to be repeated calls to `QGraphicsView::focusInEvent` and `focusOutEvent`. I have overridden these and don't seem to have much luck in stopping the loop whatever I do with these functions.

*Edit:* this appears to be a red herring, a result of switching to breakpoints inside the debugger.

There is no issue if the view is not displaying a `MyGraphicsItem`.

**Also**, I can pan and repaint the view after doing the scale, but trying to resize the window or change focus causes the problem.

Similarly, if there has not been a call to `scaleView`, I have no problems.

Perhaps I am being too vague; but please fire away with any questions I can answer to help clarify. Any help appreciated!
*Update:*

So I seem to have got it down to something to do with a subclass of my subclass of QGraphicsItem.

I took a Node from the elastic nodes example, and put this in my scene. I can zoom in and out using my sceven and view, and no hang.

I can even make Node a subclass of MyGraphicsItem rather than QGraphicsItem, and again no hand.

As soon as I put my subclass of MyGraphicsItem in the scene, I see the issue. 
Getting closer I hope!

Comment: Try upgrading your Qt - your have an ancient version. Such bugs are often fixed in subsequent releases.

Comment: I can't just change Qt version on a whim; this is in a production environment, and altering the Qt version is quite a big deal :-)

Comment: It's best to try and figure out what is actually going on (by printf()-style debugging if nothing else), but if all else fails you might want to try moving your scaleView() calls to a separate context, e.g. by calling QTimer::singleShot(0, this, SLOT(myScaleViewSlot())) rather than calling scaleView() directly from the handler. That way if the fault is due to the place within the event-loop where scaleView() is called, you can avoid the fault by calling it instead from a different part of the event loop. You'll need a way to pass the scale argument; perhaps by storing it in a member variable.

Comment: I should have been clearer; the scale function executes fine and returns to the event loop normally. But after it is executed some events then cause the problem. E.g I can pan the view (causing paint events) no problem, but I get a hang on trying to resize the window or give focus to another window

Answer (score 0):

***Further Update:***

I have found the cause of this. It seems to show that I missed an important memo somewhere.

I have a test graphics item that is NOT a MyGraphicsItem, but it is a QGraphicsLineItem, and this reproduces the problem.

I have overridden the paint method, and after a lot of elimination I have found that if I call setPen inside the paint method, my hang returns. e.g., my paint method is now:

```
void ConnectionItem::paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option,
  QWidget *widget)
{ 
  QLineF myline = line();

  QBrush brush(Qt::red); 
  QPen pen = this->pen(); 
  pen.setBrush(brush);
  **// this line results in the hang when the window is resized
  setPen(pen);**

  painter->setPen(pen);
  painter->setBrush(brush);
  painter->drawLine(myline);

}
```

So setPen (which will be QGraphicsLineItem::setPen) calls update() and then gets stuck in a loop calling QGraphicsLineItem::Paint().

Moral of the story: do not setPen or other paint related property inside the paint function!

I am not 100% clear why this is only an issue after scaling, as the paint routine is called quite happily prior to zoom.

*Edit:*

similarly

```
QPen pen = this->pen(); 
  pen.setBrush(brush);
```

causes a problem

as does calling

```
prepareGeometryChange();
```

inside the paint routine